# How to read from text file and string split it into 4 radio button? (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a text file which contains a quiz of question and answer.

```
m1 | mcq | Which of the following is an animal | table#cat#keyboard#water
m2 | mcq | which of the following is a programming language |C++#water#Air#Phone
m3 | mcq | which is the prime number | 3#4#8#10
```

My progress so far:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
string[] line = lines[0].Split( new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
string QuizQuestion = line[2].Trim();
string[] QuestionChoice = line[3].Split(new string[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
textBox.Text = QuizQuestion;
foreach(?)
{
}
```

Im trying to use foreach loop to make my radio button to act like answer choice but i am not sure how to proceed. I have inserted label and text box inside of my radio button to try which one succeeded but I fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have 4 choices, you could add 4 radiobuttons to your form, put them in a list, and do something like this:

```
string[] QuestionChoice = line[3].Split(new string[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

List<RadioButton> radioButtonList = new List<RadioButton>();

radioButtonList.Add(radioButton1);
radioButtonList.Add(radioButton2);
radioButtonList.Add(radioButton3);
radioButtonList.Add(radioButton4);

for ( int i = 0; i < radioButtonList.Count; i++ )
{
    radioButtonList[i].Content = QuestionChoice[i];
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is WPF. radio button do not have  .Text. I also try doing radiobutton.Test b4 hand

Comment: Oh THANK A LOT, after another session of testing, I went to check this website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx and found that radio button used `Content`. Thank so much